# Placing md-button over an image in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

I'd like this button:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="/icons/ic_create_48px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

to be placed at the image's top left corner:

```
<img src="{{Img}}" style="width:100%; height:200px;"/>
```

What would be the best way to do it?
Is CSS necessary? Is there any way of achieving this without the use of CSS?

Comment: You will need CSS to position the button on image

Comment: Its good practice to use `ng-src="Img"` instead of `src={{Img}}`, if you have AngularJs code insides your src attribute

Comment: I'm already used to the {{}} mark, but thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uttzv6L8/)

Css

```
.md-icon-button{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;    
    top: 8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="{{Img}}" style="width:100%; height:200px;"/>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="/icons/ic_create_48px.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. The button is not even shown

Comment: its working in fiddle. check link in that i added text("button") thats showing

Comment: Have you wrapped img with div as i mentioned? See my html code? Or may be problem in your css like other styles overwriting etc

Comment: I renamed your class and added it to the button ,but it did not work. I also tried removing the built-in md-icon-button class and adding in yours,but nothing's changed.